# It is possible to travel from London, England to Detroit, USA using a British convention travel document?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, uk, regulations

My friend wants to travel with me on a trip to Detroit. The problem is he only has a 1951 convention travel document as he is an Iranian refugee and has been living in the UK for four years.

Also does he need any kind of visa before going?

Comment: You should specify which convention, there is one about travel documents for stateless people that US did not ratify. I take it that you mean a 1951 convention travel document?

Comment: Not actually an answer but [this seems relevant](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1680/~/asylees-and-refugees-without-a-passport)

Comment: Yes the 1951 convention travel document. :)

Comment: That's the one the US ratified so that's a good thing (the other one is the 1954 convention). I would tend to think a visa is required (he definitely does not qualify for the visa waiver program, which is based on citizenship and require a machine readable passport) but I am unable to find authoritative information on that. You should probably contact the local US consulate as soon as possible. Try to get some information in writing as well as it's possible the airline would not be familiar with his situation and would be tempted to deny boarding even if he has the right to visit the US.

Answer (score 3):

He will need to get a U.S. visa, like any other foreigner without a passport from a visa-free or visa-waiver country. What type of visa depends on what he is going to the U.S. for; e.g. for tourism probably B2 or B1/B2.

Comment: A relevant reference would be helpful.